# Dynamic Hidden Form Field Data Absent From POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that, when submitted, does not post the dynamically added hidden field.

html:

```
<div>
<form action="thankyou.php" onsubmit="return validate()" id="orderform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" required /><br>
<input type="text" name="charterco" required /><br>
<input type="text" name="bname" /><br>
<input type="text" name="dtime" required /><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#orderform').submit(function(eventObj){
$('<input />').attr('type','hidden')
    .attr('id','list')
    .attr('name','shopList')
    .attr('value',sliststr>)
    .appendTo('#orderform');
return true;
});
```

POST data from Chrome DevTools:

```
name:b
email:b@b.com
charterco:b
bname:b
dtime:12:00
message:Comment
```

I can't work out what's gone wrong. My sliststr variable turns up filled and correct in my little debugging test on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Btz53/). For whatever reason, it isn't POSTing.

EDIT: As @JayBlanchard pointed out below, I am adding to the form after the POST has been written.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `serialize()`?

Comment: because the form values were already serialized by the time it get to your function

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @JayBlanchard. Why wouldn't I use POST?

Comment: You should use `serialize()` to get all of your form data into a string that is ready for posting.

Comment: It occurs to me that you're creating the hidden input in the callback of the submit function - that order will not work because the submit occurs, then the callback, where you add the input, happens. Therefore the input is not available for the submit.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand the way POST works as well as you do. My understanding is that the `<form>` tag will automatically serialize all its members when the submit action is triggered. I read the `.serialize()` documentation, and it appears to be spitting out exactly the same request string that is passed anyway (from Chrome DevTools:`name=b&email=b%40b.com&charterco=b&bname=b&dtime=12%3A00&message=Comment`). Can you clarify why I would use `serialize()` over the default functionality in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: Of course, you respond as I'm typing. :p Thanks for the catch there. I'll try a different approach.

Comment: On the other thing, I am thinking AJAX, where my brain goes when someone says "post". *You're right*, under normal circumstances, no AJAX, the form would serialize the data properly. In either case, AJAX or non-AJAX, the hidden field here would never get sent because it is formed in the callback of the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the dynamic element, set the value of it and then submit the form. Otherwise it's submitting the form and then appending the html in callback.

Try the following.

```
function validate(){
        var shoplist = [1,2,3];
        $('#orderform').append("<input type='text' name='shop' id='list'>")
        $('[name="shop"]').val(shoplist)
        $('#orderform').submit(function(eventObj){

        return true;
        });
}
```